# how to stop css effects from taking place when I click a button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, click

I have a button in html, that when clicked turns light green. I have figured out that this is due to some css I have included, but I cannot remove it due to the css being needed in other parts of the code. Is there a way I can include some css specific to the button such that for it only, there will be no effects from clicking the button? Ideally I'd like to use css/html only, but if absolutely necessary I can do with javascript/jquery.

Comment: Change class ? i suppose is `:hover` effect, you can just change class of that.

Comment: the colour change occurs when I click the button, not when I hover over it

Comment: is `:active` so  :)

Comment: is there a specific property I have to set? I tried background-color: red; but it's still light green when clicked

Comment: see my example.

Comment: Use `style=` to override whatever is making it green.  `style` on the element takes priority over css.

Comment: Without you providing any sort of detail regarding what's turning it green, any suggestion or answer will be entirely conjecture and will just result in tedious back-and-forth like the comments above.

Answer (score 2):

That's a simple example:

```css
.active{background-color:green;}
.active:active{background-color:blue;}
.notactive{background-color:green;}
```

```html
Example 1 (your situation):
<button class='active'>
pressme
</button><br>
Example 2 (change simple class):
<button class='notactive'>
pressme
</button>
<br>
Example 3 (use style):
<button class='active' style="background-color:green!important">
pressme
</button>
```

At the first example is your case, in the second example i change simple class then `:active` have no effect, in the third i used `!important` with `style`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have used ":checked" on button directly.

You can use :checked css on specific ID only. So it will stop affecting for all buttons.

If you haven't used above please mention your CSS here.